# Confusing symbols

Tags: discrete-mathematics, notation, recursive-algorithms

[image]

I saw these symbols in the text book for a subject i'm taking next semester, and I am just curious about what they mean. What is the question asking me?

Comment: It's asking to evaluate the sum of the terms depending on $i$ when $i $varies from the value $1$ to the value $6$. Similarly for the second formula, but it's the *product* of the expressions .

Answer (score 3):

The "sum" notation $\sum$ means add up the things indexed by some index. An easy example may be

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{10}i=1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10
$$

you could read this as "sum all the i's from $1$ to $10$".

$$
\sum_{j=-2}^{2}j^2=(-2)^2+(-1)^2+0^2+1^2+2^2
$$

The starting index can be any integer and you sum upto the number above the summation sign. It sometimes can be $\infty$ symbol up there, this means you sum for all the numbers.

The "product" notation works similarly

$$
\prod_{i=1}^{5}=1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdot5
$$

or

$$
\prod_{j=1}^{3}(j+10)=(1+10)\cdot(2+10)\cdot(3+10)
$$

I don't know "what the question is asking" since there is no question in your post.

Hope this helped

Answer (score 1):

See [Summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation) for $\Sigma$.

It "asks" you to compute :

> $\dfrac {2}{6.2−7}+\dfrac {2}{6.3−7}+ \ldots +\dfrac{2}{6.6−7}$.

The same with product instead of sum in the formula with the [Products of sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication#Products_of_sequences) $\Pi$ :

> $[(z+2.5)^5-5-1] \times [(z+2.6)^6-6-1] \times \ldots \times [(z+2.8)^8-8-1].$

Comment: I see, thank you!

Comment: I see, thank you!